# Dagger 2 NPE when trying to make member injection of interface type

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have problem with member injecting interface type.

Here is example:
I have interface let's call it BookActivity

```
interface BookActivity {}
```

it's simple marker interface that do nothing.

and I have two implementation:

```
BookNewActivity: Activity, BookActivity {

    @Inject someField: SomeField;

    override fonCreate(savedInstanceState:Bundle?) {
        activityComponent.inject(this)
    }

}

BookOldActivity: Activity, BookActivity {
    @Inject someField: SomeField;

override fonCreate(savedInstanceState:Bundle?) {
        activityComponent.inject(this)
    }
}

interface ActivityComponent {
    fun inject(BookActivity)
}
```

When I try to get access to someField I get NPE because dagger did not inject SomeField in my class.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you add a stack trace. 
Does it happen in runtime ?
How did you call inject (show an example) ?

Comment: @Ruokki Yes. it happens in runtime. I just updated question to show how I call inject

Comment: And a stack trace to know where is the NPE :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but this will be probably problem with dagger understanding the parent interface. You can try to have 2 inject methods for each Activity.

If an interface could have properties, you could have it there, but that's not possible :(